# Como utilizar acentuação itext 5

Tags: android, codificação-de-caracteres, itext

Não estou conseguindo utilizar acentuação no itext 5. Dei uma olhada nos exemplos do site, mas não encontrei pt-br.
Alguém saberia como utilizar?
Está sendo utilizado no Android.
Os campos da classe modelo alimentado pelas rotinas do android a acentuação funciona correta. Agora quando se cria uma nova String ele não funciona. 
Já tentei até fazer o charset da string pra utf-8 ou ISO, baixei outras fontes, usei a arial também e não funciona.

Comment: O problema já foi resolvido. O problema estava sendo ocasionado pelo charset da classe na IDE (Intellij). Estava como UTF-8 e foi alterado para ISO8859_1.

Comment: O problema já foi resolvido. O problema estava sendo ocasionado pelo charset da classe na IDE (Intellij). Estava como UTF-8 e foi alterado para ISO8859_1. Mas o que torna o problema estranho é que após se tentar realizar settext em campos edit de forma manual ocorria o mesmo problema, mesmo em classes onde já estava nesse padrão. Para não alterar a propriedade do charset no intellij e dar problema com outros desenvolvedores, foi feito diretamente a conversão da string de utf8 para iso. Ex: new String("Observação".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");